# Issue Using Graphics DrawString On Resize

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, gdi+, drawstring

### Goal

I want to display a vertical text on the left of a user control to let a user know which product they are creating/editting. Like so:

[image]

---

### How am I building it?

This user control is made up of three controls.

1. **Label** with text "Product Information". Dock=Top
2. **User Control** with a vertical draw string text of "Product #1". Dock=Left
3. **Table Layout panel** which contains X amount of user controls inside it. Dock=Fill

Here's the design view:

[image]

Here is the code for my product name user control that draws "Product #1"

```
Public Class uProductName
    Public drawString As String = "Product #1"

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        ' Call the OnPaint method of the base class.
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        ' Call methods of the System.Drawing.Graphics object.
        DrawVerticalString(e)
    End Sub

    Public Sub DrawVerticalString(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim formGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
        Dim drawFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20)
        Dim drawBrush As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black)
        Dim stringSize As New SizeF
        stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(drawString, drawFont)
        Dim x As Single = (Me.Width / 2) - (stringSize.Height / 2)
        Dim y As Single = (Me.Height / 2) - (stringSize.Width / 2)
        Dim drawFormat As New System.Drawing.StringFormat
        drawFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical
        formGraphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, x, y, drawFormat)

        drawFormat.Dispose()
        drawFont.Dispose()
        drawBrush.Dispose()
        formGraphics.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

### Current Problem

When I start selecting buttons, the table layout panel expands to display more selections and the "Product #1" text starts to glitch. See below:

[image]

I tried to set the "Double Buffer" property to true and didn't the result. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resizeredraw(v=vs.110).aspx) style for your control to indicate whether the control redraws itself when resized.

Also Instead of using `CreateGraphics()`, use the graphics object of `OnPaint` method and never dispose it, because it doesn't belong to you.

```
Public Sub New()
    ' If the base class is Control, comment the next line
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
End Sub

Public Sub DrawVerticalString(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim formGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = e.Graphics
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Alright I modified the necessary changes. I changed Me.CreateGraphics() to e.Graphics and removed the dispose calls. Although I still get the same issue.

Comment: What's the base class for `uProductName`.

Comment: uProductName is a user control with nothing inside of it. I just use it to draw the string and then I insert uProductName into my other user control called uProductInformation

Comment: The base class is `Control` or `UserControl`?

Comment: The constructor fix did it! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Also don't forget *Instead of using CreateGraphics(), use the graphics object of OnPaint method and never dispose it, because it doesn't belong to you*. It's really important. It's the most obvious problem which one can see in a painting code in `OnPaint` method :)